# Generic Autofac Container Register for All Types

Tags: .net, wcf, autofac, ioc-container

Is there any way to register generic types without registering type by type on Autofac?

Now :

```
builder.RegisterType<Repository<Authorization>>().As<IRepository<Authorization>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<Repository<Branch>>().As<IRepository<Branch>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<Repository<Customer>>().As<IRepository<Customer>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<Repository<Foo>>().As<IRepository<Foo>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
....
```

Register all off them with like:

```
builder.RegisterType<Repository<T>>().As<IRepository<T>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Have you already checked the open generics section in the documentation? http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components

Comment: @nemesv thanks for pointing section. it helped me to solve, great thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components) what i looking for.

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(BranchService).Assembly)
.Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```